# Facebook sdk: Graph API in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

In Facebook v1 graph api `user id` is the unique id for a user in multiple apps.

But in graph api v2 the `user id` does not exist, only `scope id` exists and it is not unique for multiple apps.

Is there any key or id which is unique for one user in multiple apps?

Answer (score 1):

> But in graph api v2 the user id does not exist, only scope id exists and it is not unique for multiple apps.

I am pretty sure that app-scoped ids are still *unique* - they are just not *the same* for different apps (because that’s what app-scoped means.)

> Is there any key or id which is unique for one user in multiple apps?

Only for apps that are registered as belonging to the same business.

Then you can either use the `token_for_business` field, or use the Business Mapping API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_2