# How to get signed in Facebook user id number in Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-sdk-4.0

In Android I wonder how to get a Facebook user id number after he has signed in to my app. I tried this:

```
com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId()
```

But for some reason that give me a number but it´s not the user id. 
When I go to sites like https://findmyfbid.com/ I get the correct id like "23982739223233". Even when I right click my Facebook profile picture in web browser and copy link the "referrer_profile_id=23982739223233" in the link is correct.

But when I sign in using that Facebook this `Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId()` gives me a completely different number

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GraphRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph)

in code:

```
 List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList(
                "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends");

 loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);


 loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        try {
                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                            // Application code
                                            try {
                                                Log.v("FACEBOOK LOGIN", response.toString());
                                                String fb_id = object.getString("id");   //FaceBook User ID
                                                String fb_name = object.getString("name");
                                                String fb_email = object.getString("email");
                                                String profilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fb_id + "/picture?width=200&height=200";
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.type(small)");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("FACEBOOK ERRROR", "cancelled");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Log.d("FACEBOOK ERRROR", exception.toString());
                    }
                });
```

In `Graph Request` Response you can get user's Facebook Id, name , picture and other relevant information

Comment: Thanks, not sure but I use The [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/4e7bce15b2c5ca207fb3f12e4e5e1ff2dfb15ec2/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/provider/FacebookProvider.java) to handle the sign-in flow and it already run the `GraphRequest` . I am signed in to Facebook so I thought I could get the user id in an easy way

Comment: this is not a very tough way..and it is  a guaranteed way to return correct result....you can just change your `onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult)` code to grab the ID

Comment: Thanks. Yesterday I did try the `GraphRequest` as you show a sample of but the problem was I always got the "Failure retrieving Facebook email org.json.JSONException: No value for email". The Facebook account both has a phone number and email, maybe that´s why it´s not working..

Comment: you need to make the email public in your facebook profile also you need to add permission: can check my other answer:  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116247/android-facebook-login-with-phone-number-returns-null-username/43116342#43116342) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290643/using-facebook-api-birthday-return-null-in-android/43290732#43290732)

Comment: The email is public by default and permission I need is only for the user id. Your GraphRequest  code you show in your answer works when ussing `parameters.putString("fields", "id");` the only problem is the id returned is not my sign in Facebook users. The id number is just wrong from this "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100015028951073#" id , hence the number 100015028951073...

Comment: ok I found the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177573/facebook-sdk-graph-api-in-android). Looks like there is no common id for a Facebook user but my app get assigned a unique id as soon as user accept my app. Also  [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/149151751822041)

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177573/facebook-sdk-graph-api-in-android). Looks like there is no common id for a Facebook user but my app get assigned a unique id as soon as user accept my app. Also  [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/149151751822041)

This id is what i see with

> com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId()